# Assigning the % operand in python in an iteration

Tags: python

If I have an array Numbers = [1, 2, 3] and a loop that depend on these numbers and inside the loop I have and a dictionary or some object that I want to name with the numbers in the array Numbers, how can I use the percent operand to assign the values?

So it will look like

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3]
for number in Numbers:
    dictionary_"" = {}
```

where "" would be the number.

Just using the percent operand, something like `dictionary_%g = {} %(number)`, will not work. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I put things in the correct python format but it came out all on one line, but I think you get the picture.

Answer (score 3):

You can't and/or shouldn't name variables dynamically. What you can do is create a list or a dictionary that contains these three dictionaries. A two-level data structure.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
dictionaries = {}
for number in numbers:
    dictionaries[number] = {}
```

Or, more compactly:

```
dictionaries = {number: {} for number in numbers}
```

Comment: I would say a list of dictionaries would be more appropriate in general (given the numeric keys), as well as closer to OP's desire.

Comment: Turns out this is _almost always_ a better idea

Answer (score 2):

The `exec` function can allow you to dynamically name variables.  In your case,

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3]
for number in Numbers:
    exec('dictionary_%d = {}' % number)
```

But this is really not a good idea.  It would be helpful to know what you intend to do, but if John Kugelman's answer solves your problem I would definitely recommend that over `exec`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll try to post a more specific example once I better identify the problem.